# How to insert data into JPA Entity table using a setters method from class?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, h2

Heres how I created the table and defined a set method:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

public void setContent (String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

From the controller this is how I am trying to set the content:`

```
@RequestMapping("/addBook")
@ResponseBody
public String addBook(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setContent(name);
    return name;        
}
```

When I set a new content from addBook page using the name parameter value, the content shows up on the same page. Now what I am trying to do is to insert more content to the table but I am not sure if the content is inserted to the table or not. I need to add more contents to the table. Is the setContent method updating or inserting content? And how am I supposed to see the table if it has contents?

Comment: merely setting the data won't make changes in DB. you can look into Spring Data JPA http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html ... you can ask the spring repository to save the objects in DB

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the advice. I needed to save it and that was what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a spring repository to perform CRUD operations something like

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book ,Long> {

}
```

Then in your controller class you have

```
@Autowired
private BookRepository repo;
```

now in your `addBook` method you can save book objects this ways

```
@RequestMapping("/addBook")
@ResponseBody
public String addBook(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setContent(name);
    repo.save(book);
    return name;        
}
```

your book object now will be added to your DB

Comment: @A Sdi thanks for your suggestion. I did everything else except saving the object to the repo. Now I have tried it and sent the response to a view page called book.html using thymeleaf template. In the controller this is how I sent the response:

Comment: But the page crashes and saying this: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "book.name". In the IDE console the error found as: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'sec.book.BookNames. What could be wrong?

Comment: do you have a getter method for name? If so is it private?

Comment: @A Sdi Yes I have a getter method which returns this.name and its public. Do I really need this method ? I want to display the book names in the view file and I am following the instructions for that from this page http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html. I am sending the response using the first method shown there and also how to list the names to view file.

Comment: Yes you have to have the getter in order to have access to the book's name. You may pass model attributes, Request parameters or Session attributes to your view, and they only way to have access to the value is by  getter , When have ${book.name} or ${param.name} or ${session.myBookSessionAttribute.name} in your view, you are actually invoking the getter method of the object, Thymeleaf first check the object and try to identify its type and then invokes getters to display its attributes

Comment: Regrading to exception, do you pass the Book object to your view ? if yes how do you pass it ? is it a session attribute or request param or a model attribute ? do you use the same name to pass and later get access to the attribute . You know that those are just maps key value and value itself.

Comment: @A Sdi sorry that I was not able to reply sooner. Yes I am sending the book object as model attribute to the thymeleaf view. I am populating the view exactly they way it was shown in that link i provided earlier.I think I am so close but cant figure out what is wrong there. In the get method I am just returning the book like this.book. Do I need to write any query in the BookRepository.java ? Just wondering coz I am using repo.findAll() to add the attributes to the model.

Comment: @ A Sdi in the view if i use th:text="${message} then a list appears like this for each row from the table. This is what is hown:  Entity of type sec.helloworld.Book with id: null. I want to see the names and after that use some query to get limited number of results in the list. What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: @Gustav you have to consider the objects type your are passing repo.findAll() returns a list of books , if you use  repo.findById(id); assuming that you have int id ; in your model , it returns book form DB.  lets say you have  model.addAttribute("book",  repo.find ById(id)); then you can get the book name from ${book.name} , you can use query but there are easier ways to retrieve data as well , I rather use query methods take a look here  [link][https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html]

Answer (score 0):

@Gustav - Are you also looking for something like --> what is the sql getting generated along with parameter passed ?

Then you can use something

```
  @Bean
  public Map<String, String> jpaProperties() {
    Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("eclipselink.logging.level.sql", "FINE");
    props.put("eclipselink.logging.parameters", "true");
    return props;
}
```

Comment: @Shubhasis I am not looking for any other ways at the moment but sure may be in the future. I will try this also. Thanks for your support.